# The favicon is not appearing in the search results of Bing and Google

Tags: seo, favicon

I've been helping a client design a new website, but I've noticed that the favicon isn't appearing in the search results. I've checked Google's documentation, and it states that we should use an ICO file with a size of 48x48 pixels or larger.

Here is my client's website:

[image: favicon not showing]

I've already used a 48x48-sized favicon, but it has been two weeks now, and both Bing and Google still display the default image in the search results. Does anyone know how to solve this issue?

The meta tag in the head part is:

```
<link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico">
```

Does anyone know how to solve this problem?

Comment: Two weeks isn't a lot of time to give Google to react to changes on your web site.  Google takes at least two weeks, to react to any change and sometimes as much as 6 months.  There could be a technical problem with your implementation, but it could just be a matter of waiting.

Comment: Thank you. I'll wait a bit longer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For new sites, Google insists that the website is mobile-friendly.  I just wonder, because of this it may want you to provide higher resolution icons as well.

Favicon takes longer than the website to appear.

> **Google Favicon user agent**
> Google Favicon is the user agent for downloading favicons defined by websites. It is a low-volume crawler: it may visit the home page of your site occasionally based on signals gathered during indexing, or triggered by a user request. To request that the Google Favicon user agent crawl your page, you can request indexing of your site's home page. Updates can take a few days or longer to appear in search results.

From [Define a favicon to show in search results](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/appearance/favicon-in-search)

I would request indexing and if you still haven't had a result in another two weeks, then consider providing some more resolutions (especially 192x192 for Mobile).  There are sites around that will generate all the necessary resolutions for you.

Just last week, Yandex complained about one of my sites, saying that they wanted an SVG favicon. So I would provide that too.

---

**Bing**

Sometimes things can just go wrong.  I had the same issue with one of my sites, so I wrote to support.  They fixed it.

> We got a response from engineering team and i would like to inform you that the Favicon has been updated. It is showing in Bing search results.

Comment: Thank you for your good suggestion. I will replace current favicon to be 192x192.