# Bing shows wrong favicon in SERP

Tags: search-results, bing, favicon

For some reason Bing SERPs show and old favicon of one of my clients websites. All other search engines that I tested (Google, DuckDuckGo, Yandex) show the correct icon. The website didn't use this icon for more than 6 months, so it would be weird, if this was a caching problem. What could be the reason for this and how can I fix it?

Comment: See the answers [here](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/142898/my-websites-favicon-is-not-displayed-in-bing-search-results) and [here](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/142432/the-favicon-is-not-appearing-in-the-search-results-of-bing-and-google).